# In QTP how to identify if a web element is visible on the current visible browser window

Tags: vba, qtp

On my full screen browser page the header is visible but the footer is not visible on the current window. To see the footer we needs to page down N times as the intermediate contents is populated when we page down (dynamically populate). So my problem is to know how many times i needs to page down to see the footer. Adding to this question, is it possible to know if an web element is below the current visible browser area ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using QTP for identifying and operating on the objects, you need not scroll down. Make sure that you are using strong locator properties (htmlId, ObjectId etc) for identifying the element and your code will work just fine. QTP works on the HTML source of the web page; so it is immaterial whether or not the element that you want to work on is visible or not. I am assuming there are no AJAX components here. With AJAX, you need to employ a different strategy.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I understand that it is using the AJAX components. Can you suggest the solution now ?

Comment: Well...if scrolling down is the only trigger for the AJAX to load then I guess you are stuck with mimicking the scrolls. As for identifying the elements, you better go with the Descriptive Programming way. Here is a thread that discusses how to deal with AJAX components in QTP by using the extensibility toolkit. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199534/qtp-web-extensibilty-toolkit-and-ajax

Comment: It will also help if you could share a link to your application.